# NumPy: how to calculate variance along each row of a 2D array using np.var and by hand (i.e., not using np.var; calculating each term explicitly)?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, loops, statistics, variance

I am using Python to import data from large files.  There are three columns corresponding to x, y, z data.  Each row represents a time at which the data were collected.  For example:

```
importedData = [[1, 2, 3],  <--This row: x, y, and z data at time 0.
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]];
```

1. I want to calculate the variance for each time (row).  As far as I know, one way to do this is as follows (if this is not correct, I would appreciate a heads-up):

   `varPerTimestep      = np.var(importedData,axis=1);`
2. Here's my problem.  To convince a coworker it works, I would next like to do the same thing, but avoid using np.var.  This means solving:

   `Var(S)=(⟨S_bar⋅S_bar⟩−⟨S_bar⟩⟨S_bar⟩)` # S_bar, x, y, z

I'm an intermittent Python user and just can't figure out how to do this for each row.  I found a suggestion online but don't know how to adapt the code below so it applies to each row (apologies; can't provide the link because when I do, I get an error that my code is not formatted correctly and I can't post the question; also the reason that some of the code is formatted as quotes below):

```
def variance(data, ddof=0):
     n = len(data)
     mean = sum(data) / n
     return sum((x - mean) ** 2 for x in data) / (n - ddof)
```

I have tried various things.  For example, putting the function in a loop where I first attempted just getting a row average:

```
for row in importedData:
    mean_test = np.mean(importedData,axis=1)
print(mean_test)
```

This gives me an error I can't figure out:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
> ```

I also tried this and get no output because I seem to be stuck in a loop:

> ```
>  n = len(importedData[0,:])         # Trying to get the length of each row.
>  mean = mean(importedData[0,:])     # Likewise trying to get the mean of each row.
>  deviations = [(x - mean) ** 2 for x in importedData]
>  variance = sum(deviations) / n
> ```

If anyone could please point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: Going about this in another way: why not ask your co-worker for a series of tests (e.g., a bunch of rows) that have known variance (and possibly mean), and show that your answers are correct? A few corner cases (possibly even ones that include infinity and NaNs), and some tests with more common data should be fine for this.

Comment: Thinkg about it: `np.var` has been used by thousands of people successfully. The `axis` argument may be an issue (`axis=0` or `axis=1`, for example), but the dimension of the output (provided your input is not a square array) should already validate the choice of the axis.

Comment: @00, thank you for your interest.  Yes, I certainly agree that there's no reason to be skeptical that np.var works.  I would usually respond to my coworker by pointing that out.  There is another advantage of calculating it by hand though.  The second term (third line below section "2" in my question) should show certain behavior compared to the first term for our system, so it will be useful to check that out.

Comment: Sorry, what are second and first term here? You are pointing to a line of code; that's not really a "term" to me in the mathematical sense.

Comment: For a fancier way of doing this: convert your array to a Pandas DataFrame, calculate your variance and whatever other terms you want, across the columns, and store the results in new columns. You could even index your DataFrame rows with relevant timestamps.

Comment: @00, thanks for your interest but I need to break the variance down, to convince my colleague, into the terms represented by the code I pointed out.  I'll keep plugging away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could do something like this to make things more explicit:

```py
import numpy as np 

importedData = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)

# Get means for each row
means = [row.mean() for row in importedData]

# Calculate squared errors
squared_errors = [(row-mean)**2 for row, mean in zip(importedData, means)]

# Calculate "mean for each row of squared errors" (aka the variance)
variances = [row.mean() for row in squared_errors]

# Sanity check
print(variances)
print(importedData.var(1))

# [0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666]
# [0.66666667 0.66666667 0.66666667]
```

Comment: wow, thank you.  It took me a while to figure out what you did here.  Very educational.  I appreciate knowing about being able to use "row."

Comment: Glad I can help :) I guess the most "magical" thing I did here was the `(row-mean)**2` part, since `row` is in fact an numpy array, while `mean` is just a float. The `mean` value got distributed over the `row`, then the `**2` worked elementwise on the result. This behavior caused by how the `np.ndarray` type is implemented, and the behavior is called broadcasting. I suggest you read about it as it is incredibly powerful! It is great to see you try to do things directly with `numpy`, it is MUCH faster than doing things in pure Python :)